# Expected identifier or '(' {

Tags: c, cs50

Been doing the cs50 course and I'm doing the Credit assignment. The code is finished however I can not run it on terminal, keeps on saying expected identifier '(' {

(There is a green arrow under '{' but can't find the issue)

I have been looking for the past 30 minutes and still found nothing, tried retyping and arranging my code. Here is a sample if you can find the problem.

```
void show_brand(long long card_number);
bool valid(long long credit_card);
int identify_card_length(long long c);
bool checksum(long long card_number);


int main(void)
{
    long long credit_card;
    do
    {
        credit_card = get_int("Card Number: ");
    }
    while(credit_card < 0);

    if(valid(credit_card) == true)
      show_brand(credit_card);
    else
      printf("INVALID\n");
}

bool valid(long long credit_card);
{
    int length = identify_card_length(credit_card);
    if ((length == 13 || length == 15 || length == 16) && checksum(credit_card));
       return true
    else
       return false
}

int identify_card_length(long long c);
{
    int length;
    for (length = 0; != 0; n /= 10; length++);
    return length;
}

bool checksum(long long card_number);
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; card_number != 0; i++, card_number /= 10)
   {
       if (i % 2 == 0)
           sum += card_number % 10;
       else
       {
          int digit = 2 * (card_number % 2);
          sum += digit / 10 + digit % 10;
       }
   }
  return (sum % 10) == 0;
}

void show_brand(long long card_number);
{
    if ((card_number >= 34e13 && card_number) < 35e13 || (card_number >= 37e13 && card_number < 38e13))
    printf("AMEX\n");
    else if (card_number >= 51e14 && card_number < 56e14)
    printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    else if ((card_number >= 4e12 && card_number < 5e12) || (card_number >= 4e15 && card_number < 5e15))
    printf("VISA\n");
    else
    printf("INVALID CARD\n");
}
```

Comment: Don't put a semicolon in places like `bool valid(long long credit_card);{ /****/ }`. It's breaking it from the function body. I imagine this is a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 1):

The error report is from the compiler telling you that you have a syntax error in the code.

Beginners should be told to do "incremental development". That means, do NOT type the whole program expecting it to compile and run correctly. Begin with the standard "Hello World" 5 lines, then add and TEST one line of code as you incrementally develop toward what you need.

The compiler will have told you the line containing the syntax error. Trust that message and examine the code at that line...

```
for (length = 0; != 0; n /= 10; length++);
```

This is bad...

Comment: Or the previous line, as is occasionally the case